# ¿Cuál es el error en este código?

Tags: java, poo

```
public double div(int num, int div){

    if(div==0){
        throw new DivByZeroException("El monto del IVA no puede ser cero");
        return num/div;
    }
}
```

---

Es parte de un examen que me mostraron, quisiera saber cual es el error que encuentran?

Comment: el error mas notorio es que tu funcion devuelve un tipo de dato double, pero tu estas retornando un entero,ademàs te falta un return por else en caso de que tu if no se cumpla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El retorno del resultado de la función tiene que estar afuera del `if`, sino nunca va a devolver un resultado.

El código quedaría:

```
public double div(int num, int div) {

    if (div == 0) {
        throw new DivByZeroException("El monto del IVA no puede ser cero");
    }

    return num / div;
}
```

Como comentario adicional, se puede decir que tu función en realidad hace una división entera y la devuelve como un valor flotante o doble, por lo que habría que ingresar los parámetros como `double`:

```
public double div(double num, double div) {

    if (div == 0) {
        throw new DivByZeroException("El monto del IVA no puede ser cero");
    }

    return num / div;
}
```

Comment: Una consulta, tal vez funcionaria con el ArithmeticException en vez del DivByZeroException?

Comment: Funciona con cualquier excepción, pero la DivByZeroException lo explica mejor (o la que dice Alfredo Paz)

Comment: A mi me parece que es una buena respuesta a la pregunta. el tirar una excepción dividiendo dos int (en java) es redundante, así que el "error" está en otro lado.

Comment: Yo también pienso que es innecesario el `else` una vez ya tirada la excepción, @DeRipper tal ves se considere una mejor respuesta agregando el código?

Comment: Ahí modifiqué la respuesta @KacosPro. También, me pareció que mi respuesta era suficiente, ya que el error pasaba principalmente por el lugar donde se calculaba la división.

Answer (score 0):

***OBSERVACIONES A TU CÓDIGO***

Que para mostrar una incosistencia de operaciones algorítmicas se tiene que hacer uso de `IllegalArgumentException`

Este trhown va a indicar que el parámetro o parametros recibidos son ilegales es decir que no son del tipo requerido

> Este código debería quedar así

```
public double div(int num, int div){

        if(div==0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El monto del IVA no puede ser cero");
        }
    }
```

Ahora para retornar el resultado metelo dentro del else, para que la condición se cumpla y lo retorne así

```
public double div(int num, int div){

        if(div==0){
            throw new DivByZeroException("El monto del IVA no puede ser cero");  
        }else{
          return num/div;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Que es una función de retorno y debe retornar para todas las opciones.. allí no te retorna nada.

Answer (score 0):

El error que veo es que el return está dentro de 'if' por lo que el valor de

la división de num/div está condicionado a que 'div = 0' lo cual justifica 
que

funcione solamente cuando div = 0, así que escribe el return fuera de 'if' y

ya funcionará correctamente.

Y puedes hacer un casteo para que te funcione correctamente en la parte de la division de un por ejemplo 2/10 ya que si lo dejas como está te devolverá 0 ya que estás dividiendo dos enteros el resultado será un entero.

Answer (score -1):

Veo 2 cosas:
1- El return nunca se ejecuta, pues esta despues de un throw, debe marcar error en compilación ya que el método nunca regresa el valor esperado
2- No es error en compilación, pero la división entre 2 enteros da un entero, podrías hacer un cast en la división para que fuera un double: (double) num / (double) div